# Why is boudary detected as a contour with cv2.findContours?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, boundary

[image]

If the function `cv2.findContours()` is looking for white obstacles, then yes it makes sense that boundary is considered an obstacle. But then, why would the black cap be considered an obstacle and a contour be formed on it?

Comment: Because you have a black border around the image. Also use binary images, not grayscale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findContours treats white pixels as foreground, so for this case you could just invert your image.

Assuming that you are always using a uniform background, you might want to use some preprocessing (like sobel or some kind of color classification) and then run findContours.